# PostgreSQL retrieving less than 24 hours

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why am I seeing less than 24 hours of data when I run this in postgresql

```
SELECT DISTINCT dt
FROM public.my_table
WHERE dt > now() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS'
ORDER BY dt DESC

Returns 16 hours of data
```

But when I run

```
SELECT DISTINCT dt
FROM public.my_table
WHERE dt BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 1 AND CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

Then the second query does give me the 24 hours of the previous day. I would prefer to run the first query to get the data I need. Any thoughts here? I read the documentation on INTERVAL '24 HOURS' and this should be working.

Any help here would be most appreciated!

Comment: You first query includes data starting from 24 hours ago (so, part of yesterday, and part of today), but your data ends 8 hours ago (if you only get 16 hours of data).  Your second query includes data from midnight yesterday morning up to (and including) midnight this morning.

Comment: What is the column type for `dt`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver timestamp without time zone is the column type for dt

Answer (score 1):

becasue `current_date` only returns date ant not time which means time is 00:00:00 .while `now()` has time and when you compare those values you are missing records that their time is after that time :

```
 select now() ,current_date
```

| now | current_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-31 20:30:58.853533+01 | 2021-08-31 |

Answer (score 0):

You are getting different slices of the pie:

```
create table date_time_test(dt_fld timestamp);

insert into date_time_test values ('2021-08-29 1:00:00'), ('2021-08-30 1:00:00'), ('2021-08-30 14:00:00'), ('2021-08-30 17:00:00'),('2021-08-31 5:00:00'), ('2021-08-31 16:00:00');

select * from date_time_test ;
       dt_fld        
---------------------
 2021-08-29 01:00:00
 2021-08-30 01:00:00
 2021-08-30 14:00:00
 2021-08-30 17:00:00
 2021-08-31 05:00:00
 2021-08-31 16:00:00

select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2021-08-31 15:23:06.178012-07


select * from date_time_test where dt_fld > now() - interval '24 hours';
       dt_fld        
---------------------
 2021-08-30 17:00:00
 2021-08-31 05:00:00
 2021-08-31 16:00:00


test(5432)=# select * from date_time_test where dt_fld between  current_date - 1 and current_date;
       dt_fld        
---------------------
 2021-08-30 01:00:00
 2021-08-30 14:00:00
 2021-08-30 17:00:00
```

When you are using `now()` and `interval 24 hours` you are actually going back a 24 hour period from the time you run the query.
When you use `CURRENT_DATE - 1` and `CURRENT_DATE` you are covering the previous date, which is a 24 hour period but not the same one as the `now()` query.

Comment: With `now()` and `interval 24 hours` why am I getting just the previous 16 hours of data from the time I run the query and not all 24 hours? My postgres database has data for every hour for the past 30 days. I'm stumped. If I do `WHERE dt > now() - interval '33 hours'` then I do get the previous 24 hours.

Comment: Have you verified that there are data for every hour going back 24 hours?  What are the timestamps returned if you eliminate the `DISTINCT`?